# Code executes sometimes and gives error for the other times

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba

I am trying to automate a process in excel.  I have called two macros from Python.  The code executes successfully sometimes and sometimes gives an error.  I have saved the macros and the python file in the same location.

```
import os,os.path
import win32com.client
Path = 'xyz'
if os.path.exists(r'D:\Code\ABC.xlsx'):
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath('D:\Code\ABC.xlsx'))
    xl.Application.Run(Macro.xlsm!Module1.Macro1, Path)
    xl.Application.Run(Macro.xlsm!Module2.Macro2)
    xl.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    del xl
```

The error that it gives at times is:

> (-2147352567, 'Exception occured.',(0,''Microsoft Excel','Cannot run
>   macro 'D:\Code\Macro.xlsm!Module1.Macro1'. The macro may not be
>   available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled',
>   'xlmain11.chm, 0, -2146827284'), None)

I am getting a new error, which is constant:
//winp-oaf-118/FldrRedir_3$/Data/Macro.xlsm' cannot be found.Check your spelling, or try a different path.

Comment: When you view them in the developer screen, are your macros stored in a sheet, in ThisWorkbook or on your profile?  What are your macro security settings set to?

Comment: Your code doesn't open `Macro.xlsm` --- how do you know it's open?

Comment: @Plato77 Macros are stored in the workbook itself. Macros are enabled.

Comment: You may need to set the working directory. Just having the files in the same folder may not work always. Try: `os.chdir(r'D:\Code\')`